# CSS Visibility Hidden or Collapse is not working

Tags: jquery, css

Good Day!

My Problem is: The Right arrow is not collapsing even the condition's answer is true. It only work when I resized the window to a smaller size, but when I try to resize it to a larger one, it doesn't.

Maybe I am missing something. Hope you can help me guys. Thank you in advance.

Here's the snippet (Please expand)

```js
   

$('#left-button').css({visibility: 'collapse'});
$('#right-button').click(function() {
 event.preventDefault();
 $('#content').animate({
  scrollLeft: "+=160px"
 }, "moderate" );
});
   
$('#left-button').click(function() {
 event.preventDefault();
 $('#content').animate({
  scrollLeft: "-=160px"
 }, "moderate");
});
   
$('#content').scroll(function () {
 if (this.scrollWidth - $(this).scrollLeft() <= $(this).width() + 0){
  console.log('right end');
  $('#right-button').css({visibility: 'collapse'});
  $('#left-button').css("visibility","visible");
 }
          
 if ($(this).scrollLeft() == 0) {
  console.log('left end');
  $('#right-button').css("visibility","visible");
  $('#left-button').css("visibility","collapse");
 }
          
 if (($(this).scrollLeft() != 0)&&(this.scrollWidth - $(this).scrollLeft() > $(this).width() + 0)) {
  console.log('mid');
  $('#right-button').css("visibility","visible");
  $('#left-button').css("visibility","visible");
 }
          
});
```

```css
.left{
 height: 154px;
 border: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.right{
 height: 154px;
 border: 0;
 text-align: left;
}

div.internal{
 margin-right: 10px;
 min-width: 150px;
 max-width:150px !important;  
 min-height: 150px;
 max-height:150px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 border: 2px solid transparent;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

img{
 min-width: 146px;
 max-width:146px !important;
 min-height: 146px;
 max-height:146px;
}

div.internal:hover{
 border: 2px solid orange;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.center{
 width: 954px;
 height: 152px;
 overflow: hidden !important;
 /*will change this to hidden later to deny scolling to user*/
 white-space: nowrap;
 border-radius: 76px 76px 76px 76px;
 font-size: 0px;
 display: flex;
 /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}


#left-button, #right-button{
   vertical-align:sub;
   font-size: 50px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   cursor:pointer;
   text-align: center;
}
.fa-angle-right,.fa-angle-left{
  padding-top:50px;
}
.content{
  display: flex;
  max-height: 154px;
  margin:auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 content">
    <div class="left">
      <span id="left-button">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left" style="float: right"></i>&nbsp;
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="center" id="content">
      <div class="internal">
          <img class="" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="internal">
          <img class="" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="internal">
          <img class="" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="internal">
          <img class="" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="internal">
          <img class="" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="internal">
          <img class="" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="internal">
          <img class="" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="internal">
          <img class="" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
      </div>
      <div class="internal">
          <img class="" src="https://i0.wp.com/vanillicon.com/655060357b259bcfb74db87a5909097c_200.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <span id="right-button">&nbsp;
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="float: left"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found two problems...

1. With the code you supply, you never enter into the "right end" condition. The operation inside of the `if` is never true, because of a little difference (0.4...), so never goes in. I don't know where it's coming (maybe some padding), I've been able to make it work using 0.5 instead of 0, but check it out to see if there's a better value.
2. On the other side, your're using `if` for the three conditions, and when you get to the right, it executes but then also enters in your third option, and show the button again. You can solve it using `else if` for the second and third condition.

Here you have a working fiddle...

https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/k5ck3ssr/

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. The problem seems fixed.

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding